# Macro defination in ios custom framework is not working

Tags: ios, debugging, macros, frameworks

Can please any one tell how to use macros like debuglog by using print some information to console while building a framework in ios, and it should work when application developer runs the application with this framework in debug mode.

Comment: You are mixing up concepts. You can see '#pragma warning msg' when you build the project, if you want warnings for certain conditions (like you didn't define something on the build line). if you want developers using your library to get log messages, you have to write your own little "log" capability, which should output text to 'std error'. Obviously you can write a macro that ends up using fprintf(stderr, C-Format-String, args...);

Comment: Hi David I am not mixing up concepts, I am just asking is there any way to do like that, can you please explain it clearly about fprintf what you are saying, how can i use it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) define a global BOOL in your library with some odd name:

```
BOOL GzRkYr22; // (use your framework name as prefix or suffix)
```

2) provide some means for your users to turn the flag on or off:

```
- (void)enabledDebuggingMessages:(BOOL)val;
```

That method will set the global flag.

3) Put this in your .pch file

```
extern BOOL GzRkYr22;

#define Log(format, ...) \
do { if(GzRkYr22 ) NSLog(format, \
## __VA_ARGS__); \
} while(NO)
```

4) Sprinkle your code with Log messages:

```
Log(@"Just did %d operations", someNumber);
```

5) If you later decide you want to only have log messages for a “debug” version of your library, but totally disable them for "production" versions:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG // some macro that is defined or not defined for the different modes

#define Log(format, ...) \
do { if(GzRkYr22 ) NSLog(format, \
## __VA_ARGS__); \
} while(NO)

#else

#define Log(format, ...)

#endif
```

Comment: @David H Please give me some more explanation on using of do while, why not only if condition. And NSLog(format, \
## __VA_ARGS__); is this the format I need to use.

Comment: @Reddy do while is an old trick to insure that when you put a ';' after the macro, that the macro expands to one single line of code, and that you do not get unintended branching if you use it in a single if statement "if(something) MACRO(...);